# Dagger Hilt crash in Google Play Console

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, google-play, dagger-hilt

I'm using Hilt library (version 2.36) in my project and getting the following crash appears in my Google Play Console, crash happens to all android versions and all devices, mostly I guess in Android 9..

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager.createComponent
```

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3430)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3614)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2199)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:112)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager.createComponent (ActivityComponentManager.java:76)
  at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager.generatedComponent (ActivityComponentManager.java:66)
  at com.kingim.activities.Hilt_MainActivity.generatedComponent (Hilt_MainActivity.java:40)
  at com.kingim.activities.Hilt_MainActivity.inject (Hilt_MainActivity.java:62)
  at com.kingim.activities.Hilt_MainActivity$1.onContextAvailable (Hilt_MainActivity.java:33)
  at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable (ContextAwareHelper.java:99)
  at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate (ComponentActivity.java:322)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:273)
  at com.kingim.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate (BaseActivity.kt:77)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7458)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7448)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1286)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3409)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3614)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2199)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:112)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

BaseActivity and MainActivity(that extends BaseActivity) are displayed in my gist:
https://gist.github.com/eldartsa/ba3e0f47e279d21242aa09b1c51e863f

Comment: what at com.kingim.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate (BaseActivity.kt:77)?

Comment: @IR42 I added links to my classes

Comment: Hi @eldartsa did you manage to fix this issue? I'm seeing a couple of exceptions like yours but mine only appear on Huawei devices

Comment: @Adelino, same for me. I only get this exception on the usual suspects — Huaweis and Samsung Galaxys… Have you found a solution?

Comment: @JohnDoe unfortunately I'm still trying to understand what is happening

Answer (score 2):

So [this article](https://medium.com/@pablobaxter/what-happened-to-my-subclass-android-application-924c91bafcac) should explain it. But, essentially the `Application` class will always be created before `Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver` so you can safely call `getApplication()`. `ContentProvider` though can be instantiated before `Application`. Chances are you have an issue occurring with backupMode. check your manifest for `android:allowBackup="true"`.